# Dynamically created form fields keep having the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically add some text fields to my page with this line of code:

```
var textboxCount = 0;

$('#addFields').on('click', function(){

var TextField = document.createElement("input");

TextField.setAttribute("type", "text");
TextField.setAttribute("value", textboxCount);
TextField.setAttribute("name", "textbox");
TextField.setAttribute("class", "foo");
TextField.setAttribute("id", "textbox" + textboxCount);
TextField.setAttribute('onkeyup','doSomething('+textboxCount+');'); // for FF
TextField.onkeyup = function() {doSomething(textboxCount);}; // for IE

jQuery('#TextfieldList').append(eleText);
textboxCount += 1; //Increment the count

});
```

Now I need the unique ID of the field in this function:

```
function doSomething(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

But when I call the function, I keep getting the same ID with every added field. The value in the textfield is correct though.

Comment: You really don't need to use `.setAttribute()` for all of those properties. You can just refer to properties directly on the element (like, `TextField.name = "textbox";`).  The only exception is the "type" property, which for old versions of IE (and maybe new?) must be established when the element is created: `document.createElement("<input type='text'>")` - that will work in other browsers too.

Comment: @Pointy which browsers will `document.createElement("<input type='text'>")` work in?

Comment: @Musa I thought it would work anywhere but apparently not. I'm pretty sure my old brain isn't lying to me that it's necessary in IE (old ones at least) however.

Comment: and the whole thing could be added as a string `$('<input type="text" class="foo" id="textbox'+textboxCount+'">').appendTo('#TextfieldList);` with more attributes of course.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes of course; I didn't even think about the fact that there's jQuery in play too!

Comment: Of course this ignores the fact that `eleText` is undefined - I took that as a typo/paste issue

Answer (score 2):

Extremely common problem. Change the keyup handler:

```
TextField.onkeyup = function(textboxCount) {
  return function() {
    doSomething(textboxCount);}; // for IE
  };
}(textboxCount);
```

(Get rid of the "For FF" line; it's not necessary at all.)

If you don't introduce a new lexical scope somehow, then all of your event handlers will be referring to the exact same "textboxCount" variable. By doing something like what I've shown above (and there are variations), you ensure that each event handler has its own private copy of the counter as it stood at the time the handler was created.

Comment: I realize that there are dozens (at least) of variations on this question, but sometimes the isomorphism is not obvious to a programmer who's gotten themselves wrapped up in this problem already :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to get the id of an element in its own event handler you can bypass the whole closure issue by just referencing `this.id`, where `this` is the element and id is its `id` property

```
TextField.onkeyup = function() {doSomething(this.id);};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the jQuery library you have in play:

```
$('#addFields').on('click', function () {
    var thisId = $('.foo').length + 1;
    var TextField = '<input type="text" name="textbox" class="foo" value="' + thisId + '" id="textbox' + thisId + '">';
    jQuery(TextField).appendTo('#TextfieldList');
});
$('#TextfieldList').on('keyup', '.foo', function () {
    doSomething($(this).attr('id'));
    // or 
    doSomething(this.id);
});
function doSomething(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Sample jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mHT7Z/